# How to find out why the server closes or loses connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, openvpn

We have a Ubunutu 16.04LTS Server which is an application server and vpn server at the same time running in VMWare. 
We have atm two clients which are connected with the OpenVPN Server 24/7. Both clients reconnect at the same time every hour (not exactly an hour but mostly between 30min and 50min). Also ssh connections which don't use OpenVPN break at the same time.

How can we figure out why the server loses or closes connections?

Comment: How is your connection bandwidth? One odd source of random disconnects I've experienced is connection saturation.

Comment: One of the clients and the ssh-clients are in the same network. The Bandwith from within the network through vpn is 13.6Mbits/sec and using the non VPN IP-adress 360 Kbit/s - 13.6 Mbits/s.

Comment: EDIT: the last one is also 13.6 Mbits/s

Comment: If you set the verbose (`verb`) level to >= 5 in the `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` file, does the log file (`openvpn-status.log`) indicates anything useful at all?

Comment: No I can't see anything helpful there.